# Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument

Tags: r, invalid-argument

I was doing a simple simulation. I entered the code below to look at what happens when the repetition number (which is "n") gets bigger. But this only ends with the error:

```
Error in integer(n) : invalid 'length' argument
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.

The code I used is below:

```
n <- c(1 : 100000)

p <- mean(replicate(n, any(duplicated(sample(1:365, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))))
```

Comment: Start form `?replicate`,  *n  integer: the number of replications.* , i.e *n* is supposed to be scalar, not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

When using `replicate`, the first argument should be a single integer informing the function how many replicates you want. But you are passing a *vector* of integers.

What you need to do is loop through `n` and get the mean for *each* call to `replicate`. The typical way to do this in R is with `sapply`:

```r
n <- c(1 : 1000)

p <- sapply(n, function(i) {
  mean(replicate(i, any(duplicated(sample(1:365, size = 30, replace = TRUE)))))
})
```

Now we can see what happens as the sample size gets larger:

```r
plot(p)
```

[image]

Also note that I limited n to 1:1000. It would likely take hours to run the number of replicates in your sample code, given the size of the vectors being generated.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow, this is my first time using stack overflow, which is great! Thank you for your help.